# TextView Edit Text is not responding to Click Events

Tags: android

I have a layout with three TextViews, two TextViews are responding to Click Events but the last one is not responding. I am using Navigation to navigate to other fragments. The OnClick method is called inside an adapter which implements view.OnClickListener.

> XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/defaultMargin"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <TextView
                android:text="How CADO works"
                style="@style/CircularBook"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
                android:id="@+id/howCadoWorks"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <View
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/howCadoWorks"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/pinkishGray"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:id="@+id/view3"></View>

        <TextView
                android:text="FAQ"
                style="@style/CircularBook"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
                android:id="@+id/faqs"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <View
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/faqs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/pinkishGray"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:id="@+id/view4"></View>

        <TextView
                android:text="Contact Us"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow_right"
                style="@style/CircularBook"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/buttonHeight"
                android:id="@+id/contactus"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> OnClickMethod

```
 public void onClick(@Nullable View view) {
        NavController var3 = Navigation.findNavController(view);

        if(view.getId()==R.id.contactus){
           **var3.navigate(R.id.contactus_fragment);**
           return;
        }
        else if (view.getId()==R.id.faqs){
            var3.navigate(R.id.faqFragmnt);
            return;
        }
        else if (view.getId()==R.id.howCadoWorks){
          Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Feature is in Progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // var3.navigate(R.id.contactus_fragment);
          return;
        }
        else
        {

        }
}
```

I have tried multiple ways, rechecked id's as well but nothing is working.

Comment: Make sure you have register click listner for your textview like this `yourTextView.setOnClickListner(this)`

Answer (score 5):

as [@Nilesh Rathod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod) said, you need to make sure that all your text view have set an on click listener like:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

or you can also:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Here you put the code you want to use for the specific textView click event
        }
    });
```

Comment: Good, if you'll run into any other errors or problems, feel free to ask for help :)

Comment: Yes sure :) TIA

Comment: @dennisrufigill Do not forget to accept the answer, to indicate to others as well that you do not need an answer on this question anymore